# Changing file details in php such as title and album

Tags: php

Can I change file details in php?

For example:In an mp3 file, I want to change title and album.

Please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.id3.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'NEW_TITLE',
    'album' => 'NEW_ALBUM'
    );
id3_set_tag('file.mp3', $data);
```